# Definition of a Smooth Surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm learning about conformal mapping but I have no elementary knowledge in differential geometry. We were introduced the concept of a smooth surface and I have several questions.

Definition: A set $S\subset R^3$ is a surface if $\exists U \subset R^2$ open and a $C^\infty$ bijection $f:U\to S$ such that $f^{-1}$ is continuous and $\partial_{x}f \times \partial_{y} f \neq 0$.

My first question is why do we need $\partial_{x}f \times \partial_{y} f \neq 0$. My friend explained to me this is to guanrantee a sensible tangent plane. I can see why that's the case because if the cross product is zero then there would be infinite candidates for tangent plane. But I can't imagine what the surface would look like if it's indeed zero.

Secondly, initially I thought $C^\infty$ serves to guanrantee the existence of a tangent plane but it turns out its not sufficient. Can anyone explain to me how this happens?

Thirdly, why do we need $C^\infty$ instead of just $C^1$? Since it seems to me a tangent plane only requires first order differentiablity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The typical example is the apex of cone: see for example https://www.brainjam.ca/papers/LimitNormals.pdf.

(2) Because of (1).

(3) In the context of differentiable manifolds, the $C^\infty$ condition avoid technical difficulties in the definition of *tangent space*. See [An example of a derivation at a point on a $C^k$-manifold which is not a tangent vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73677/an-example-of-a-derivation-at-a-point-on-a-ck-manifold-which-is-not-a-tangent).